# How can I show desktop icons in Elementary OS?

Tags: desktop, desktop-environment, elementary-os, icons

How can I show icons on the desktop in Elementary OS Luna?

I tried using `gnome-tweak-tool` and `gconf-editor` but they didn't work.

Comment: Have you followed: http://elementarytips.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/enable-desktop-icons-in-elementary-luna.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Install Nautulus (avoiding the whole gnome desktop with `--no-install-recommends`)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -–no-install-recommends nautilus dconf-tools
   ```
2. Open `dconf-editor`. Click twice on `org` -> `gnome` -> `nautilus` -> `preferences` -> `desktop-is-home-dir`.  It should be left disabled.
3. Edit `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`.  Add `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop` to the bottom of the file and remove any existing `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR` lines if they exist.
4. Create a `Desktop` directory under your home directory.
5. From a terminal, run `nautilus -n`
6. To make it run automatically open `dconf-editor` and navigate to `org` -> `pantheon` -> `cerbere`.  In the monitored process line, add `nautilus -n` entry.  It should look something like this:

   ```
   ['wingpanel', 'plank', 'slingshot-launcher --silent', 'nautilus -n']
   ```

For more details, see [this post from elementarytips.blogspot.co.uk](http://elementarytips.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/enable-desktop-icons-in-elementary-luna.html).

Comment: still valid in Freya? I cannot see org -> gnome -> nautilus -> preferences -> desktop-is-home-dir in dconf-editor

Comment: @cipricus Doesn't seem like it. Nautilus won't start in Freya.

Comment: (Here's are instructions that works https://elementaryforums.com/index.php?threads/enable-desktop-icons-and-right-click-in-elementaryos-freya.198/#post-231)