# Desktop shortcuts in Elementary OS

Tags: elementary-os, desktop-shortcuts

Is there any way to have files in desktop in Elementary Luna OS. I have checked and tried installing tweak but couldn't move the files to desktop.

Comment: you can find the Answer here:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154280/83339

It's worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this function has deliberately been omitted from elementaryOS.  It was a specific design choice. But you can at least enable My Computer or Trash bin.

With Pantheon (the default file manager in Luna) you can’t bring files or folders onto the desktop. But in Nautilus, it’s possible. Run

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

and install it.

Then type the same `gnome-tweak-tool` to launch it.

From the Desktop menu you can adjust the desktop to your liking. Check Have file manager handle the desktop and other options like display **My Computer** or **Trash** icon.

However, we need to make these changes boot with the OS. Go to the System Settings > Startup Applications > Add. Input the Name (Nautilus, for example) and type `nautilus -n` in Command.

Comment: @NaveenShanmugam So you said you'll let me know, did it work?

Comment: Oh yeah. I tried the tweak tool and it wasn't kinda satisfactory for me. So I switched to Ubuntu 14.4. Thanks for the suggestion.